# Error 'unable to get local issuer certificate' while working on react-native(expo-cli)

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to run a react-native(expo) application in a corporate network.

I am executing the following command:

`npx expo start`

It gives me an error:

> FetchError: request to https://api.expo.dev/v2/versions/latest failed, reason: unable to get local issuer certificate

What I have tried:

1. Imported company provided certificate
2. Added path of certificate in .npmrc file
3. Updated strict-ssl to false in the .npmrc file

Please help to get rid of this issue.

Answer (score 1):

This happens to me most of the time, I got it working one time by setting `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0` in the `.env` file but the expo version was <49.

Answer (score 0):

And another solution to get is started is by turning off your internet connection which will start from the local dependencies but you will have dependencies unreliable in offline mode

Comment: You can leave a comment on such an answer, not in the actual thread!